# Transitions in Flash Actionscript 3.0

Tags: flash, function, tween

I'm new to flash and unfortunately our teacher hasn't taught us how to make transitions. I have tried researching them, and it seems there are 100's of ways to do it. In my instance, I haven't found a valid way. How can I put in a transition between pictures being loaded?

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import fl.transitions.*;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;

home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, takeToHomeZerg);
sarahkerrigan_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addsarahkerrigan);
izsha_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addizsha);
abathur_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addabathur);


var sarahkerriganAdd:Loader = new Loader();
var izshaAdd:Loader = new Loader();
var abathurAdd:Loader = new Loader();


var sarahkerrigan:URLRequest = new URLRequest("zerg/sarahkerrigan.jpg");
var izsha:URLRequest = new URLRequest("zerg/izsha.jpg");
var abathur:URLRequest = new URLRequest("zerg/abathur.jpg");


sarahkerriganAdd.visible = false;
izshaAdd.visible = false;
abathurAdd.visible = false;


addChild(sarahkerriganAdd);
addChild(izshaAdd);
addChild (abathurAdd);


function takeToHomeZerg (evt:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(1);
    removeChild(sarahkerriganAdd);
    removeChild(izshaAdd);
    removeChild (abathurAdd);

}

function addsarahkerrigan (evt:MouseEvent):void{
    sarahkerriganAdd.load(sarahkerrigan);
    sarahkerriganAdd.x = 275;
    sarahkerriganAdd.y = 32;
    sarahkerriganAdd.scaleX = .2618;
    sarahkerriganAdd.scaleY = .28;
    sarahkerriganAdd.visible = true;
    izshaAdd.visible = false;
    abathurAdd.visible = false;

}

function addizsha (evt:MouseEvent):void{
    izshaAdd.load(izsha);
    izshaAdd.x = 275;
    izshaAdd.y = 32;
    izshaAdd.scaleX = .2618;
    izshaAdd.scaleY = .28;
    izshaAdd.visible = true;
    sarahkerriganAdd.visible = false;
    abathurAdd.visible = false;


}
function addabathur (evt:MouseEvent):void{
    abathurAdd.load(abathur);
    abathurAdd.x = 275;
    abathurAdd.y = 32;
    abathurAdd.scaleX = .2618;
    abathurAdd.scaleY = .28;
    abathurAdd.visible = true;
    izshaAdd.visible = false;
    sarahkerriganAdd.visible = false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to make transitions, but the most convenient (and optimized) I think, is GreenSock library. Take look at their [examples page](http://www.greensock.com/get-started-tweening/)!

P.S. You can also do it with AS3 native tools only, but it wouldn't be so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you fade out a movieclip without GreenSock:

```
// add a listener that calls a function on each frame 
// (i.e. 15, 24 or 30 times per second depending on your movie settings)
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,fadeOutMyClip)

function fadeOutMyClip(e:Event) {
    if (myClip.alpha > 0) { 
// decrease the transparency of the mc by 1 percent each frame
// at 30 fps, it'll take 3.3 seconds, and at 15 fps it'll take 6.6 seconds
        myClip.alpha-=0.01
    } else {
// don't forget to remove the listener when it's no longer needed
// you could also remove the now-transparent movieclip from stage completely, 
// if you're not planning on fading it back again
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,fadeOutMyClip)
    }
}
```